# How to link navigation bar in django?

Tags: html, django

I am new to django I want to create a responsive website im using django for it, the website works fine except for one thing when the website is switched to mobile view the navigation bar is not working.

This is my urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from app import views

urlpatterns =[

    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^about/',views.about,name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/',views.contact,name='contact'),
    url(r'^portfolio_project1/',views.portfolio_project1,name='portfolio_project1'),
    url(r'^portfolio_project2/',views.portfolio_project2,name='portfolio_project2'),
    url(r'^portfolio_project3/',views.portfolio_project1,name='portfolio_project3'),
    url(r'^resume/',views.resume,name='resume'),
    url(r'^portfolio/',views.portfolio,name='portfolio'),

]
```

This is my header section

```html
    <header role="banner" class="banner clearfix" id="banner">
            <div class="section-content">
                <div class="branding clearfix">
                    <figure id="logo"><a href="{% url "index" %}" title="Return to Home Page"><img src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}" alt="my logo" /></a></figure>
                    <h1><a href="{% url "index" %}" title="Return to Home Page">Sriram</a></h1>
                    <h2>Portfolio Website</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#nav" aria-controls="nav" class="nav-menu-toggle control" id="menu-toggle">Menu</a>
        </header>
        <nav role="navigation" class="nav clearfix main-nav" id="nav">
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="{% url "about" %}">About</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="{% url "resume" %}">Resume</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="{% url "portfolio" %}">Portfolio</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="{% url "portfolio_project1" %}">Project 1</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="{% url "portfolio_project2" %}">Project 2</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="{% url "portfolio_project3" %}">Project 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="{% url "contact" %}">Contact</a></li>
            </ul><!--/.nav-menu-->
        </nav>
```

This is my views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse


def index (request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def about (request):
    return render(request,'about.html')

def contact (request):
    return render(request,'contact.html')

def portfolio_project1 (request):
    return render(request,'portfolio_project1.html')

def portfolio_project2 (request):
    return render(request,'portfolio_project2.html')

def portfolio_project3 (request):
    return render(request,'portfolio_project3.html')

def resume (request):
    return render(request,'resume.html')

def portfolio (request):
    return render(request,'portfolio.html')
```

These are the scripts linked

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{% static "js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" %}"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="{% static "js/plugins.js" %}"></script>

        <!-- Widowtamer -->
        <script src="{% static "js/vendor/widowtamer-min.js" %}"></script>

        <script src="{% static "js/main.js" %}></script>
```

I have tested the site without using django it works fine. But if i use django when i switch to mobile view the menu button is not working everything else works fine.

Comment: How are you hosting the app? If its apache, you need to configure the static dir. The static files are not served by django but directly by apache. and it seems that your css or js file is not getting loaded properly, which is the reason behind the issue

Comment: I am not using apache. I have already added the static dir in the settings.py when i resize my browser the nav bar changes to menu bar when i click it its not working

Answer (score 3):

To solve this ...

in your `main.html` (other people choose to call it `base.html`) reference this Django template tag in the head tag session:

`{% include "navbar.html" %}`

and the navigation bar will appear on all your website session

Answer (score 2):

Recommend watching this series for learning Django. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW

To make a nav bar with bootstrap

Add this starter [Template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) to base.html

Next Add this to the top of the body

```
<!-- A grey horizontal navbar that becomes vertical on small screens -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>`
```

Source https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp

If you didn't find the starter template in this link

Then here is the code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you're done Your code should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>BASE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- A grey horizontal navbar that becomes vertical on small screens -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">

    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'link1' %}">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'link2' %}">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'link3' %}">Link 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'link4' %}">Link 4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'link5' %}">Link 5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  
  </nav>

  
        {% block content %}
        Replace Me!
        {% endblock %}

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I created an HTML "navbar.html" containing my navbar code**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Qina Smart Map</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href={%url "home"%}>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href={%url "admin"%}>Admin</a>
            </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href={%url "about"%}>About</a>
            </li>
         </div>
      </nav>
```

**then I used this tag in my HTML files**

```
{%include 'navbar.html'%}
```

**my url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', qinaschools.views.home, name='home'),
    path('about/', qinaschools.views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^qinaschools_dataset/$', qinaschools_dataset, name='qinaschools'),
    path('admin/', qinaschools.views.admin, name='admin'),

]
```

Comment: it looks good now, cleaning my comments its not needed for now,